# javascript convert date into strftime format

Tags: javascript, date, strftime

if i have date format like below :

```
Mon Sep 07 2015 10:38:55 GMT+0700 (WIB)
```

how to convert it into date with format bellow :

```
07082015
```

thanks before master

Comment: http://momentjs.com/docs/

Comment: Hey @ArunPJohny, the solution is not there: `var a = 'Mon Sep 07 2015 10:38:55 GMT+0700 (WIB)';
    a = new Date().getTime(a);
    console.log(a);`